# apply string of boolean on list

Tags: python, list, boolean

I have two lists.

First:

```
["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
```

Second:

```
["T", "F", "F"]
```

and I want to apply the boolean list to make the first list into:

```
["a<4", "b>3", "c>6"]
```

Change the smaller into greater depend on the boolean list.

How can I do this?

Comment: Other than using a dictionary of dictionaries?

Comment: If both lists have same size, then simply iterate on it. (pseudo code)
`for i in list1:
  if not boolList[i]:
    change_element_list1`

If my comment helps you, then I'll put them as an answer. just let me know

Comment: What about changing from greater to smaller or that isn't a requirement?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm coming from R so I don't like loops and if statements. If all you need to do is to change from smaller to greater by condition, you can easily vectorize this using `numpy`. Something among these lines

```
l1 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
l2 = ["T", "F", "F"]

import numpy as np
n1 = np.array(l1)
n2 = np.array(l2) == "F"
n1[n2] = np.char.replace(n1[n2], "<", ">") 
print n1
## ['a<4' 'b>3' 'c>6']
```

Comment: Aha that's overkilling

Comment: @aahung Why an overkill? A simple vectorization instead of writing loops and if statements? When I work in Python I work solely with numpy arrays as this makes my code 10 times shorter.

Comment: No offense, it is indeed a good (and elegant) solution. What I mean is NumPy is not a pre-installed package, installing a 3rd package for solving it is overkilling.

Answer (score 1):

You can try:

```
>>> list1 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
>>> list2 = ["T", "F", "F"]
>>> for index in range(len(list1)):
    if list2[index] == "F":
        temp_data = (list1[index]).replace("<",">")
        list1[index] = temp_data

>>> print list1
['a<4', 'b>3', 'c>6']
```

Answer (score 1):

You may want this

```
def transform(statement, corretness):
    if corretness == 'F':
        if '<' in statement:
            return statement.replace('<', '>')
        else:
            return statement.replace('>', '<')
    return statement

statements = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
correctness = ["T", "F", "F"]

statements = [transform(s, c) for (s, c) in zip(statements, correctness)]
// ['a<4', 'b>3', 'c>6']
```

Answer (score 1):

I have not tested the code. I am writing this directly to this editor.
I hope this helps you.

```
a = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
b = ["T", "F", "F"]
newa = list()
for i in range(len(a)):
    if b[i] == 'F':
        if '<' in a[i]:
            newa.append(a[i].replace("<",">"))
        elif '>' in a[i]:
            newa.append(a[i].replace(">","<"))
    else:
        newa.append(a[i])

print newa
```

Answer (score 1):

```
list1 = ["a<4", "b<3", "c<6"]
list2 = ["T", "F", "F"]
def replace(k):
    return k.replace("<",">") if "<" in k else k.replace(">","<")
list2= [replace(i) if j=="F" else i for i,j in zip(list1,list2)]
print(list2)
```

This reverses the condition based on the second list.

Answer (score 0):

Just for fun:

```
[''.join([a, '<>'[(o == "<") ^ (c == "T")], n]) for (a, o, n), c in zip(x, y)]
```

Example:

```
>>> x = ["a<1", "b<2", "c>3", "d>4"]
>>> y = ["T", "F", "F", "T"]
>>> [''.join([a, '<>'[(o == "<") ^ (c == "T")], n]) for (a, o, n), c in zip(x, y)]
['a<1', 'b>2', 'c<3', 'd>4']
```